# Creating yii2 dynamic pages with url: www.example.com/pageName

Tags: php, url, routes, seo, yii2

In my system, users need to have their profile pages. It is requested from me that these pages will be displayed in url like this:

```
www.example.com/John-Doe

www.example.com/Mary-Smith
```

How to achieve these URLs in yii2 ? These John-Doe and Mary-Smith can be user usernames or profile names. For example I have field in user table called "name" and it will hold names "John Doe", "Mary Smith". Pay attention that I need SEO friendly URLs with "-" instead of blank spaces.

URLs like this: 
    www.example.com/profile/view?id=1 
are not an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
www.example.com/John-Doe

www.example.com/Mary-Smith
```

I think there is no normal way to use these urls because at first controller (in your case it's `ProfileController`) needs to be determined. From these urls it's impossible to do.

Second problem with the urls you provided - uniqueness is not guaranteed. What if another user with name `John Doe` will sign up on site?

Look for example at your profile link at Stack Overflow:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/4395794/black-room-boy
```

It's not `http://stackoverflow.com/black-room-boy` and not even `http://stackoverflow.com/users/black-room-boy`.

Combining `id` and `name` is more widespread and robust approach. Also they can be combined with dash like this: `http://stackoverflow.com/users/4395794-black-room-boy`

Yii 2 has built-in behavior for this, it's called [SluggableBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior.html).

Attach it to your model:

```
use yii\behaviors\SluggableBehavior;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'name',
            // In case of attribute that contains slug has different name
            // 'slugAttribute' => 'alias',
        ],
    ];
}
```

For your specific url format you can also specify `$value`:

```
'value' => function ($event) {
    return str_replace(' ', '-', $this->name);
}
```

This is just an example of generating custom slug. Correct it according to your `name` attribute features and validation / filtering before save.

Another way of achieving unique url is setting [$ensureUnique](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior.html#$ensureUnique-detail) property to `true`.

So in case of `John-Doe` existense `John-Doe-1` slug will be generated and so on.

Note that you can also specify your own unique generator by setting [$uniqueSlugGenerator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior.html#$uniqueSlugGenerator-detail) callable.

Personally I don't like this approach.

If you choose the option similar to what Stack Overflow uses, then add this to your url rules:

```
'profile/<id:\d+>/<slug:[-a-zA-Z]+>' => 'profile/view',
```

In `ProfileController`:

```
public function actionView($id, $slug)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id, $slug);
    ...
}

protected function findModel($id, $slug)
{
    if (($model = User::findOne(['id' => $id, 'name' => $slug]) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('User was not found.');
    }
}
```

But actually `id` is enough to find user. Stack Overflow does redirect if you access with correct `id` but different `slug`. The redirects occurs when you are completely skipping the name too.

For example `http://stackoverflow.com/users/4395794/black-room-bo` redirects to original page `http://stackoverflow.com/users/4395794/black-room-boy` to avoid content duplicates that are undesirable for SEO.

If you want use this as well, modify `findModel()` method like so:

```
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = User::findOne($id) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('User was not found.');
    }
}
```

And `actionView()` like so:

```
public function actionView($id, $slug = null)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($slug != $model->slug) {
        return $this->redirect(['profile/view', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $model->slug]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But what If I want to find user by his id+name or just id, but I do not want to display id in URL, I want to display only name. Is that possible with slug or custom urlManager rules ?

Comment: It's possible with slugs like 'John-Doe-1' (increment) or 'John-Doe-255' / '255-John-Doe'. (id). Specify $ensureUnique and $uniqueSlugGenerator (in case of combining with ids) in SluggableBehavior. Then modify findModel to find by slug and actions to receive $slug as get parameter.

Comment: Do you mean to modify findModel and viewAction line in your code exmple ( Profile controller ) ?

Comment: Yes. With the urls like 'John-Doe' in case of multiple users with the exact same name when finding model with findOne() it's not guaranteed that the result model contains desired user.

Comment: Nice answer! is there any way to map static pages like 'privacy-policy'  with  siteControllers's content() method with passing 2 or any numeric as parameter? My idea is to fetch content from db with that id.

Comment: Note, Yii2 has a utility method to turn a string into a slug `Inflector::slug()`, may be better than using `str_replace()`