# Yii2 article name in url

Tags: url, routes, yii2

I have action 'show' for showing articles in blog whose URL is: `localhost/myblog/web/blog/blog/post?id=4`.

I want the URL to be `localhost/myblog/web/blog/blog/post/unique/title-of-article`.  How to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You must use [SluggableBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior.html) in your model to generate the url part which is human readable. This data is saved saved to your database model.
With this slug and some modifications to your controller and UrlManager rules you can create what you want.

This would be a complete tutorial and this was [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986102/creating-yii2-dynamic-pages-with-url-www-example-com-pagename) here on Stackoverflow.
If you need more detailed tutorials I would suggest to google. Multiple tutorials can be easily found like [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-sluggable-behavior--cms-23222).